# How to subclass int and make it mutable

Tags: python, subclass, immutability

Is it possible to subclass `int` and make it mutable?

Consider the following class:

```
class CustomBitVector(int):

    # bit 7
    @property
    def seventh_property(self):
        return bool(self & (1 << 7))

    @seventh_property.setter
    def seventh_property(self, val):
        self |= bool(val) << 7

    # bit 6
    @property
    def sixth_property(self):
        return bool(self & (1 << 6))

    @sixth_property.setter
    def sixth_property(self, val):
        self |= bool(val) << 6


    # ... a few more of these ...

    # bit 0
    @property
    def zeroth_property(self):
        return bool(self & (1 << 0))

    @zeroth_property.setter
    def zeroth_property(self, val):
        self |= bool(val) << 0
```

I trying to make a nice interface to a bit vector. I'm reading a proprietary protocol off of a socket and I've made classes to represent the messages I'm sending/receiving. Often these messages include bit vectors and it would be nice to deal with them like this.

This already works great for reading the bit vector values, but setting them doesn't work because `int` is immutable.

If I rewrite one of the setters like:

```
@sixth_property.setter
def sixth_property(self, val):
    print 'before:', self
    self |= bool(val) << 6
    print 'after:', self
```

Then I get this behavior:

```
In [2]: c = CustomBitVector()

In [3]: c.sixth_property
Out[3]: False

In [4]: c.sixth_property = True
before: 0
after: 64

In [5]: c
Out[5]: 0

In [6]: c.sixth_property
Out[6]: False
```

I can see my folly ... I'm assigning to `self` instead of modifying it. How can I modify `self` in this case?

Any crazy hack to make this happen? Maybe using a metaclass or something?

---

UPDATE

I forgot to mention a requirement:

Instances of `CustomBitVector` must behave like `int`. In particular, I need to be able to pass them to `struct.pack`

Comment: You can not make the integer itself mutable (unless you write an extension in C), but you can certainly use it instead of extending it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to subclass int and make it mutable?

Sort of. You can add all the mutable parts you want, but you can't touch the int parts, so the degree of mutability you can add won't help you.

Instead, don't use an int subclass. Use a regular object that stores an int. If you want to be able to pass it to `struct.pack` like an int, implement an `__index__` method to define how to interpret your object as an int:

```
class IntLike(object): # not IntLike(int):
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value
    def __index__(self):
        return self.value
    ...
```

You can implement additional methods like `__or__` for `|` and `__ior__` for in-place, mutative `|=`. Don't try to push too hard for complete interoperability with ints, though; for example, don't try to make your objects usable as dict keys. They're mutable, after all.

If it's really important to you that your class is an `int` subclass, you're going to have to sacrifice the `c.sixth_property = True` syntax you want. You'll have to pick an alternative like `c = c.with_sixth_property(True)`, and implement things non-mutatively.

Comment: works like a champ, and yes, the most important thing is that it can be used with `struct.pack`.

Answer (score 1):

I just package up my proof-of-concept code and upload a mutableint package to PyPi.

https://pypi.org/project/mutableint/

Here is the usage.

```
from mutableint import MutableInt

# create a mutable integer with value 10 
a = MutableInt(10)

# change the value of a to 11
a.set(11)
```

Comment: How to make mutableint with a custom function when `__repr__` or `__str__` called?

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution.  It also make an integer iteratable too.

```
import ctypes

class MutableInt(int):
    def __init__(self, val = 0):
        self._val = val

    def __int__(self):
        return self._val

    def __index__(self):
        return self._val

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._val)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._val)

    def __iter__(self):
        self._iter_cnt = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._iter_cnt == 0:
            self._iter_cnt = 1
            return self._val
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def set(self, val):
        self._val = val
        ob_digit = ctypes.c_long.from_address(id(self)+24)
        ob_digit.value = val
```

Comment: This breaks in all kinds of ways. For example, `x = MutableInt(0); x.set(1); print(x)` crashes immediately when I test it.