# Python collection of references to immutables

Tags: python, reference, mutation

Is there a way in python to obtain a list of references? Meaning, a collection of things that automatically changes when I change one of the internal things, without the need to refer to the collection itself.

Something that would allow what I show in my example

```py
# What happens
a = 1
b = 2
L = [a, b]
print(L) # [1, 2]

b = 3
print(L) # [1, 2]


# I would like to have something like
a = 1
b = 2
ra = ref(a)
rb = ref(b)
L = [ra, rb]
print(L) # [1, 2]

b = 3
print(L) # [1, 3]
```

**EDIT**
My first example *would* work if numbers were mutable in python. I.e. if reassignment (for example: `b = 3`) would mean "mutate the memory of the object which we are referring to via the label 'b'".

My first example work with mutable elements of the list (e.g. if I build a list of lists, and mutate - without reassigning! - the inner lists).

Therefore, to be more specific, my question is: do we have any chance to have such behavior when the collection contains immutable elements?

(In particular I am interested in lists of callables).

Comment: You basically answered your own question - Python already refers to each object by their reference.  The problem is when you *reassign* the object reference for an immutable object, or just haven't used the available methods for a mutable object.  When you're dealing with a collection of immutable elements, you should be working directly with the collection itself.

Comment: This might also interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935204/how-to-subclass-int-and-make-it-mutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a way. I just wrap immutables with a mutable wrapper.

For example, if we want to have mutable integers:

```py
class mut_int:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def mutate(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)

a = mut_int(1)
L = [a, a]
print(L) # [1, 1]

# from now on, we assume we don't have access to L anymore

a.mutate(2) # simulating the mutable a = 2
print(L) # [2, 2] # we changed L without accessing it directly, nice!
```

For mutable callables, similarly:

```py
class mut_callable:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def mutate(self, new_func):
        self.func = new_func

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.func)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

f = mut_callable(lambda x: x)
L = [f, lambda x: f(x) + f(x), lambda x: f(f(x))]
print([g(2) for g in L])
# Out: [2, 4, 2] 
# i.e. [identity(2), 2+2, identity(identity(2))]

# from now on, we assume we don't have access to L anymore

f.mutate(lambda x: x**2)
print([g(2) for g in L])
# Out: [4, 8, 16]
# i.e. [square(2), 2+2, square(square(2))]
```

Unfortunately, this is a little brittle, due to python's dynamic nature and no possibility of overloading the assignment (`a = 3`) operator. As soon as one uses a usual assignment on a mutable wrapper, the wrapper will be simply lost, and we are back to square one.

```py
a = mut_int(1)
L = [a, a]
print(L) # [1, 1]
a.mutate(2)
print(L) # [2, 2] good so far

a = 3 # !ACHTUNG! We did not stick to the api, and a is no more a mut_int!
print(L) # still [2, 2] :(
a.mutate(4) # AttributeError
```

If somebody finds a more elegant and/or ergonomic and/or robust solution, I'm still looking forward to it!

Answer (score 1):

Before printing the new value of L, store value b again in L, please find below code:

```
a = 1
b = 2
L = [a, b]
print(L) # [1, 2]
b = 3
L=[a, b]
print(L) # [1, 3]
```

But this method isn't efficient. Way to update the List item is only by index.As follows:

```
a = 1
b = 2
L = [a, b]
print(L) # [1, 2]
b = 3
L[1]=b
print(L) # [1, 3]
```

We can't do that by the way that you were trying to do using references in Python.
When you put an integer in a list, the list holds a copy of the integer. It doesn't matter whether the integer was originally a variable, a literal value, the result of a function call, or something else; by the time the list sees it, it's just an integer value.

Comment: My requirement is that I want to mutate what's inside L *without ever* referring to L again. That's the point of having a collection of references, so that if I have, say, L[a, b, a, a, a, c, a, d], I can just say "change a" and all a's in L will have changed. Also, I edited my question to make it more specific, since it's really about collections of immutables only.

Comment: [a,b,a,a,b,c]- this would construct a list which is mutable.Integers are immutable in nature. When you iterate over this list you can change the contents of the list because the list is mutable, however, the integers themselves do not change as they are immutable. What Python does here (behind the scenes) is create a new integer object of value 1, and switch the pointer to that new object.

Comment: Thank you. As I said in my previous comment, I am looking for a workaround for cases in which I don't have access to a reference to the collection of immutables, but still want to change it. Or, even if I had it, I would like a more ergonomic way to change all values which depend on some variable (that may appear multiple times in the collection, for example). See my answer for a way to implement this workaround.